# Adding a post changes value of the previous one instead of adding a new one

Tags: php

I'm writing a page where I want to add posts, but after I add a title and content of the post and go to the main page where the php function which adds posts is called, the previously added post just changes title and content to the new values.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
function drawPost(){
        $id=$_COOKIE['id'];
        $connect = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'data');
        $title=$connect->query("SELECT `title` FROM `posts` WHERE `id`='$id'")->fetch_object()->title;
        $content=$connect->query("SELECT `content` FROM posts WHERE `id`='$id'")->fetch_object()->content;
        $img=$connect->query("SELECT `img` FROM posts WHERE `id`='$id'")->fetch_object()->img;
            $result2 = '<div class="center">';
            $result2 .= '<h1><a class="titles" href="post.php">';
            $result2 .= $title;
            $result2 .= '</a></h1>';
            $result2 .= '<h2 class="date">';
            $result2 .=  date ('F, jS Y');
            $result2 .= '</h2>';
            $result2 .= '<img src="stories.jpg" alt="" class="thumb">';
            $result2 .= '<h2 class="content">';
            $result2 .= $content;
            $result2 .= '</h2>';
            $result2 .= '</div>';
            return $result2;
}
?>
```

On the main page I just call this function:

```
<?php
  echo drawPost();
?>
```

**EDIT:**
The first post with added content looks like the left side of the picture I included, and then when I add the second post I want the first one to move down a little bit and make a place for the second one. But instead of that when I add the second post the php just changes values of the first one.

Deleted the image, I can't add the third one because I'm new here and don't have enough reputation.

**EDIT 2:**
Previous post, and the new post are shown. It just replaces values and stays in the same place. 
Oh and the post below called 'The title of the second post' is just added in html(it'll be done in php as soon as I figure out or get an answer to this question), php didn't make it.
[image: Previous post]

[image: New Post]

Comment: Why are you making 3 queries instead of 1 query that returns all 3 columns?

Comment: I'm not grasping the question.

Comment: *"Adding a post changes value of the previous one instead of adding a new one"* - You should probably have posted the query for that, maybe MySQL's complaining of an already existing entry or similar and you didn't check for errors. I dont' know; I'm picking at straws.

Comment: No, that's not the case. I checked for them.

Comment: @Barmar because I don't know how to do it

Comment: `select title, content, img from posts where id = '$id'`.

Comment: Fetch into `$row`, and use `$row->title`, `$row->content`, and `$row->img`.

Comment: You're not using `$img`, you just have a hard-coded `<img src="stories.jpg" alt="" class="thumb">`

Comment: yeah, I know that. I'll take care of it later. Now I just wanna focus on why it's changing the values of the previous post and not adding a new one

Comment: It's not changing anything. You're showing both posts, but with the same image.

Comment: You're showing both of them side by side.

Comment: If you're referring to the picture I included, that's not what it looks like. It just shows one post, I add a new one and the values just change. I checked with Inspect in a browser too. I just conjoined two screenshots because I couldn't upload two pictures for unknown reasons.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by adding a new one. Your script just shows one post, the one whose ID is in the cookie.

Comment: Yeah, it just shows one post but this post doesn't stay on the page, when I add the new one the previous one gets replaced. I want it to work like a news feed, like on Facebook for example. The old posts just go down and down the page, they don't get replaced and disappear.

Comment: You just keep saying the same thing. I don't know what you mean by "add the new one". How are you adding this HTML to the page? Are you calling the function in a loop, making AJAX calls? Where does the cookie come from?

Comment: I add it just with the code I included, I include the php file with this function on my main page and then just call the function. I'm not calling it in a loop or making AJAX calls. Cookie comes from the page where I add the posts.  Every post, when it's made, gets an id and this id is input into the database. So every time when a post is made I fetch id from the database and make it into the cookie.